# NSOutlineview customizations

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I need to change the font color of the grouped items titles in a NSOutlineview , and hide the show/hide buttons when you hover your mouse over to the right hand side of a grouped item.

I could not find how to do this on any of Apple documentation. can anyone point me to the correct direction...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a view-based or cell-based NSOutlineView?

Comment: cell based NSOutlineView

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a view-based NSOutlineView. Because NSView inherits from NSResponder, you can use these events to do what you need:

```
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent
- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

More information in the [NSResponder docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsresponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Note that after 10.5, you use [NSTrackingArea](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH8-SW1) objects in order to receive mouseEntered:, mouseExited:, and mouseMoved: events.